# AngularJS 2 select a HTML element and append it to another element on button click

Tags: html, angular

I want to select a HTML element and append it to another div on a click of a button using **Angular2**.
Startup HMTL

```
<div class="parent">
<ul class="level1">
    <li>
        <div class="otherdiv">
            This is a test
            <button md-raised-button type="button" color="primary">Clone</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When the button is clicked I expect to have following structure

```
<div class="parent">
<ul class="level1">
    <li>
        <div class="otherdiv">
            This is a test
            <button md-raised-button type="button" color="primary">Clone</button>
        </div>
        <ul class="level2">
            <li>
                <div class="otherdiv">
                    This is a test
                    <button md-raised-button type="button" color="primary">Clone</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Not sure how can I achieve this. Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: thanks @Arvind Sivam, I missed that tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clone()` in jquery.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lor7hmyk/)

Here is the code:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $("#level1").clone().attr('id', 'level2').insertAfter("#level1");
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul id="level1">
    <li>
      <div class="otherdiv">
        This is a test
        <button md-raised-button type="button" color="primary">Clone</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Using angluarJs also we can do the same by using `ng-repeat`.You can repeat every time by adding the number.

[**ANGULAR FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5gsk5uyg/)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('ctrlParent', function($scope) {
  $scope.myNumber = 1;
  $scope.myFun = function() {
    $scope.myNumber = $scope.myNumber + 1;
  }
  $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrlParent">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber) track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span>
        <button ng-click="myFun()">Click to CLone
            </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but what I am looking for is angular 2 way of doing it(I know I can use jQuery in angular2 app too), still your answer is also appreciated.

Comment: @NiranjanNimbalkar check the solution using angularjs